# Responsive CSS table layout make one cell act like a row

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a layout design I was trying to accomplish via `display:table-cell`. This however may not be the best option, as it is causing me problems.

The desired outcome:

I wish that on smaller screens (less than 992px) to have a layout like so:

```
+----+----+
|    |    |
+----+----+
|         |
+---------+
```

But then on larger screens (greater than 992px) to have this layout:

```
+--+--+--+
|  |  |  |
+--+--+--+
```

The caveat is that they may not all have the same size content, and I want them to stretch vertically to all be the same height.

I am currently accomplishing this with :

```
.table {
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}    

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:50%;
    position:relative;
    padding:0px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

My problem arises from the fact that in order to get the third cell to wrap around, I need to give it it's own row. But then, the cell will only spread to fit the first 50% (under the first cell) and not stretch 100%. This can be fixed by making the second row it's own table, but then, getting the two tables side-by-side at the right screen size is proving difficult as well.

If there is a better way to make the divs match height that would be ideal. I am using bootstrap, so using its grids would be easy, so long as I can make them all the same height.

Note: Faux columns do not work for my scenario as the backgrounds would not be appropriately colored/spaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `table-layout:fixed` to ensure the cells to get equal width.

For the `@media` query part, use `display:table-caption` for the last cell, and set `caption-side:bottom` to specify the placement.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7kpcf46r/ (resize the output frame and see)

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .cell:last-child {
        display: table-caption;
        caption-side: bottom;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">One Line</div>
    <div class="cell">Two<br/>Lines</div>
    <div class="cell">More<br/>Than two<br/>Lines</div>
</div>
```

Comment: My pleasure :) it's quite a classic question to me. I'm sure it will get more hits in the future, it would be better if you could improve the post title and simplify the question.

Comment: of course, though this was the best I could come up with. If you have any suggestions I'd be happy to update it.

Comment: @Pangloss , was just going through your answer , do you reckon a site like http://www.iahchemicals.com/ can be made responsive ,maybe not 100% .. but to an extent ? what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries to style contents based upon the width of the screen, for example, given the HTML:

```
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
<div class="cell"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
/* Setting the defaults, to apply regardless of
   screen width: */
html, body {
    /* removing margin and padding, setting
       font-size to 0 in order to prevent
       new-lines creating space between sibling
       elements: */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

/* resetting the font-size for all descendants of
   the body element: */
body * {
    font-size: 16px;
}

div.cell {
    /* border-box, causes the browser to include
       the width of the borders and padding within
       the assigned width of the element: */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* instead of table-cell, causing elements
       to default to displaying side-by-side: */
    display: inline-block;
    /* the default behaviour is to show at
       50% of the width of the parent (body)
       element: */
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40vh;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

/*
   Note: in this demo I'm using screen widths of
         of 600px (min/max) to demonstrate the
   principles within the constraints of JS Fiddle's
   limited viewport. In your project, obviously, use
   your required width of 992px.
*/

/* in screen-widths less than 600px
   the last-child has a width of 100%: */
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
    div.cell:last-child {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* in screen-widths greater than 600px
   div.cell elements have a width of 33%
   (including the last-child) to display
   side-by-side across the viewport: */
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    div.cell {
        width: 33%;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kq0g38oq/1/).

References:

- [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: I am already using media queries to detect the screen size of 992px. The problem with your example is that you define the height of the element. I need the height to be fluid based on the tallest content.

Comment: Could you possibly show enough of your own code that we can reproduce your problem? Think *minimal* / "[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" code.

Comment: Didn't think code was necessary to describe the problem. I've updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sharf224/kq0g38oq/2/ to demonstraight what I mean. When the first two cells are in a row I want them to have the same height. The third cell doesn't matter. when all 3 are side by side, they should all be the same height.

Comment: @sharf: are these three elements inside of a wrapper of some kind? And code is (*almost*) always necessary. I'd suggest adding said code to your question, as well as a link to either the JS Fiddle you offered above, or to another that you think might better demonstrate your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/z1kwrm8p/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell" id="c1">ABCD</div><!--
 --><div class="cell" id="c2">EFGH</div><!--
 --><div class="cell" id="c3">XYZ PQRS ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP QRSTUVWXYZ</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background:#009933;
}    

.cell {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
}


#c1 {
    background:#99ccff;
}

#c2 {
    background:#ff9966;
}  

#c3 {
    width:100%;
    background:#66FF66;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  /* rules that only apply for canvases narrower than 992px */
    .table {
        display:table;
    }

    .cell {
        display:table-cell;
        width:33.3%;
    }    

    #c3 {
        width:33.3%;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty close, but in the collapsed view (2 on top, 1 on bottom) if one of those two is taller than the other you encounter the same problem of them not being the same height.